# How to cast an Instance of QueryDocumentsnapshots into a List - Flutter, Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am a little stuck in my project to learn more about flutter and hope you can help me out or give me some advice for some lecture :)

I have two collections in my firestore db - one user and one group collection.

Inside my user docs I have an array with some group ids.
The Groups collection is also very simple - only some collections with unique ids and as fields only name and description.

Now I want a List with all my Groups the User is a member - so I have to get a List with the Group IDs and then query the Database to get back all Group Data for this IDs

By now I am getting back the group IDs and the right Data for the groups.
But how can I map this Data into a List for a Listview?

My Code - _buildBody is called inside a scaffold for the body.

```
Widget _buildBody() {

User _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(_currentUser.uid);

return StreamBuilder(
    stream: docRef.snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError){
        return Error();
      }
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Loading();
      }
      
      //Get all my Group Ids
      final List<dynamic> documents = snapshot.data.get('groups');
      

      Future<List<Map>> _groups = getGroups(documents);
      
      //return ListView with Data
      return ListView(...);

    }

);



Future <List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> getGroups(List<dynamic> documents) async{

       List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> group_docs;
       List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = new List();
      
 QuerySnapshot collectionSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
                                    collection('groups').where('id', whereIn: documents).get();

 //Now I have all QueryDocumentSnapshots as a instance inside the list
group_docs = collectionSnapshot.docs;


 //What now?! :D




return list;
```

}

Big thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be as follows:

```
List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = [];

list = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() ).toList();
```

A tip: As you can also see, I modified your instance of the List class. It does not influence the answer, of course, but I recommend that you get used to instantiating lists in this way.

Comment: Big Thx - it works now.
Maybe stupid question, but cause I am still learning - Why would you instantiate like this?

Comment: @learn2Dev It is not a silly question. It's part of it! It is a recommendation of the documentation. Even if you look at Android Studio, you'll see that the way you did it is obsolete. The same goes for map {}. Do not forget to mark as the answer to the problem. =)

Comment: Thx man. So maybe a good idea to prevent it only search for code snippets after 2020 :)